# Interaction between two or more charts in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have 2 charts in one container, one is a Bar column chart and another is a radar chart. Now I want to make interaction between the charts, like when I click on one of  the column of the barcolumn chart the radar will show some changes. I made those charts using ExtJS MVC. So I think I have to make function calls from controller.. 
here is my controller..

```
Ext.define('Gamma.controller.ControlFile', {

extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

//define the stores
stores : ['BarColumn','RadarView','VoiceCallStore','SMSCallStore','MMSCallStore','GPRSUsageStore'],
//define the models 
models : ['BarCol','radar','VoiceCallModel','SMSCallModel','MMSCallModel','GPRSUsageModel'],
//define the views
views : ['BarColumnChart','LineChart','RadarChart','VoicePie','SMSPie','MMSPie','GPRSPie'],

refs:[{

    ref:'radarChart',
    selector:'radar'


}],

init : function() { 

}
})
```

please any one help me....